# Checking then Adding items to QCompleter model

Tags: qt, qt4, qtextedit, qcompleter

I am currently working on a code editor written in Qt,

I have managed to implement most of the features which I desire, i.e. auto completion and syntax highlighting but there is one problem which I can't figure out.

I have created a model for which the `QCompleter` uses, which is fine for things like html tags and c++ keywords such as `if else` etc.

But I would like to add variables to the completer as they are entered by the user.

So I created an event on the `QTextEdit` which will get the word (I know I need to check to make sure that it is a variable etc but I just want to get it working for now).

```
void TextEdit::checkWord()
{
    //going to get the previous word and try to do something with it
    QTextCursor tc = textCursor();
    tc.movePosition(QTextCursor::PreviousWord);
    tc.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
    QString word = tc.selectedText();
    //check to see it is in the model
}
```

But now I want to work out how to check to see if that word is already in the `QCompleter`s model and if it isn't how do I add it?

I have tried the following:

```
QAbstractItemModel *m = completer->model();
//dont know what to do with it now :(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `word` is in your `QCompleter` really by using

```
QAbstractItemModel *m = completer->model();
```

as you can see, method `model()` returns `const` pointer.

That is good for checking procedure, you can check like this:

```
bool matched = false;
QString etalon("second");
QStringListModel *strModel = qobject_cast<QStringListModel*>(completer.model());
if (strModel!=NULL)
    foreach (QString str, strModel->stringList()) {
        if (str == etalon)
        {
            matched = true;
            break;
        }
    }
qDebug()<<matched;
```

---

But for your purposes, I recommend you to declare `QStringListModel`, and connect it to your completer, and then, all of operations you'll must do thru your model, according to Qt's principles of MVC programming (http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/model-view-programming.html).

Your code can be like this:

```
// declaration
QCompleter completer;
QStringListModel completerModel;

// initialization
completer.setModel(&completerModel);
QStringList stringListForCompleter;
stringListForCompleter << "first" << "second" << "third";
completerModel.setStringList(stringListForCompleter);

// adding new word to your completer list
completerModel.setStringList(completerModel.stringList() << "New Word");
```

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your reply, I am indeed using a stringList for my model, the method of adding the new word to the end of the list, will that allow duplicate words to be added? or would still use the method you added to check to see if it was in there if not then add? forgive my ignorance :)